# How to connect with cloud based load testing using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate,Now I'm doing some tasks using Visual Studio testing. I tried to perform load test using cloud based load testing. I saw some video series,on that series they using Visual Studio 2013 and some advanced technologies. Now my question is, Can I do this in cloud based load testing using Visual Stdio 2010?

Thanks, (Sorry for my slang).

Answer (score 0):

The answers to your question are here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing

You do need a Team Services Account that can be created here: https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs

Good luck!

Comment: The question is about the 2010 version of Visual Studio.